# Can't select Local IIS in Servers section of Project properties

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I'm following a Pluralsight course in which I create a Xamarin.Forms app, I'm at the stage where I add a new Azure Mobile Service Project and then have to edit the properties.

In the properties page I select the Web tab and I need to change the dropdown in the Servers section to Local IIS, but this option isn't available to me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first install the IIS, it is not by default in windows

> Click Start and then click Control Panel.
>
> In Control Panel, click Programs and then click Turn Windows features
>   on or off.
>
> In the Windows Features dialog box, click Internet Information
>   Services and then click OK.

Here an article in [Microsoft technic](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725762.aspx)